# Array of Input for Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In MYSQL, I have created a Stored Procedure with single ID as an input value and it returns the data related to the ID.

Now I have to pass an array of IDs in each instance and it should return data for all the input IDs.

Is there any solution to make it work without changing the stored procedure?

Comment: By array I take it you mean a comma separated string? And I suspect you would have to change the procedure to split the string.

Comment: Since it is a common stored procedure which is used in many places,I could not change that.So I was asking is there any solution to make reuse of it

Comment: How do you intend to pass the array to the procedure?

Comment: Pass the string to a new procedure, which splits the string and calls the resuseable procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ......

BEGIN
SELECT 
   SELECTSTATEMENT1;
   SELECTSTATEMENT2;
   SELECTSTATEMENTn;
END
```

..and pass the relevant id's in the array to the select statements.